# WooCommerce - PHP Output Buffering - Why does my cart content number not change on add to cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this HTML / PHP markup that I want to change the number of items in the cart when a user adds an item to the cart.

Right now, it only increases the number of items in the cart on page refresh - not dynamically like I want it to.

```html
$cart = WC()->cart;


if ( $cart ) {
    $cart_contents_count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_contents_total = $cart->total;
}

$checkout_url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) );
?>

<div class="ecommerce-nav">

    <!-- Cart Link -->

    <a id="open-cart" class="sa-link" href="/cart/" data-open-wfc="true">

        <span title="<?php echo $cart_contents_count ?> items in your cart" aria-label="<?php echo $cart_contents_count ?> items in your cart" class="shopping-cart-icon">
            <?php
            //Icon
            require_once( get_template_directory() . '/assets/images/header-icons/Cart.svg' );

            //Number of items
            if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) {
                echo '<span class="shopping-cart-contents-count">' . $cart_contents_count . '</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </span>
        <span class="cart-contents-total sa-link__description">
            <?php echo ( $cart_contents_total > 0 ) ? '<sup>$</sup>' . $cart_contents_total : ""; ?>
        </span>

    </a>

// More items and code here
```

Here's my function that executes on the Woocommerce Cart Fragments filter hook:

```html
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {

    $cart = WC()->cart;
    if ( $cart ) {
        $cart_contents_count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        $cart_contents_total = $cart->total;
    }
    ob_start();
    ?>
<a id="open-cart" class="sa-link" href="/cart/" data-open-wfc="true">

    <span title="<?php echo $cart_contents_count ?> items in your cart"
        aria-label="<?php echo $cart_contents_count ?> items in your cart" class="shopping-cart-icon">
        <?php
            //Icon
            require_once( get_template_directory() . '/assets/images/header-icons/Cart.svg' );

            //Number of items
        
            if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) {
                echo '<span class="shopping-cart-contents-count">' . $cart_contents_count . '</span>';
            }
            ?>
    </span>

    <span
        class="sa-link__description">
        <?php echo ( $cart_contents_total > 0 ) ? '<sup>$</sup>' . $cart_contents_total : ""; ?>
    </span>

</a>

<?php
    $fragments['#open-cart'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
```

I want this line:...

```php
 echo '<span class="shopping-cart-contents-count">' . $cart_contents_count . '</span>';
```

...and this line...

```php
 <?php echo ( $cart_contents_total > 0 ) ? '<sup>$</sup>' . $cart_contents_total : ""; ?>
```

...To Update when a user clicks add to cart. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - it appears in WooCommerce 7.8, the refreshed fragments script isn't loaded unless you are using the mini cart functionality.

I fixed this by adding this line of code in my wp_enqueue_scripts callback:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
```

[More information on this here](https://developer.woo.com/2023/05/24/woocommerce-7-8-beta-1-released/).